# Using IronPython at a hosting company

Tags: ironpython, web-hosting, shared-hosting

Does anyone have experience running IronPython in a shared hosting environment?  Am using one hosting company but they don't support it.  It's a project mixing ASP.NET MVC 4 with IronPython.

I would do a VM somewhere if all else fails, but figured I give this a shot to save a few bucks. #lazystackoverflow

Thanks,
-rob

Comment: I don't think that this would make much sense from a business viewpoint: if you want to provide python services just offer python/django services, if you want to provide C# or .Net/Asp services just provide them; i think that IronPython is just a good exercise and it can't wet the appetite of any hosting provider. Hosting providers loves to offers free/opensource solutions i can't imagine who wants to mix an extremely powerful open-source language like python with a closed-source solution, full of potential legal issues, when this mix will add nothing valuable to the final service.

Comment: Hey, mixing things up is FUN! :-)  We can use IronRuby/IronPython to create procedural DSL (domain-specific languages) scripts where just a database or a store won't do.

Answer (score 0):

IronPython should work in shared hosting environments. I'm assuming they have some sort of partial-trust setup and not a full-trust environment; if it's full-trust, there's no issues. If not, it should still work, but it hasn't been as heavily tested. You have to deploy it with your project (in the bin directory), but aside from that, it should just work.

You can use NuGet to add is to your project ("IronPython"), or find the necessary files in the Platforms/Net40 directory of an installation or the zip file.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the input.  I'll give it a shot and report back.